# Change border color of Selectize control for validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, selectize.js

I have a form which is using selectize for select drop downs.  In my validation code, I add the ID of any empty input to an array, and then add the requiredField class to each of those elements.

I am able to successfully get the IDs of selectize inputs that have not been changed put into the array, so that part is working. When I look at the rendered code, my requiredField class is added to the selectize element, so that is working also.  But the border color is not changing even with the added class.

The code works for all of my text inputs, but I can't figure out why it's not working for the selectize drop downs.  I looked at the rendered code, and it looks like selectize is creating an element with a different ID, so I tried using that ID (adding -selectize to the end) but alas that's not working either.  Here is my code:

The CSS

```css
    .requiredField{
        border: thin solid red !important;
    }
```

The Javascript

```js
            var empty_fields=[];
            $(".code_description").each(function(){
                if ($(this).attr("value")==="") {
                    empty_fields.push($(this).attr("id"));
                }
            });
            $(".code_select").each(function(){
                if ($(this).find('option:selected').length === 0) {
                    empty_fields.push($(this).attr("id"));
                    empty_fields.push($(this).attr("id")+'-selectized');
                }                
            });
            //console.log(empty_fields);
            var fld_text="<p>Review required fields</p>";
            $('#error-messages').html(fld_text);
            empty_fields.forEach(element => $("#"+element).addClass("requiredField"));
```

Selectize Initialization:

```js
           // initialize newCodes selectize control      
            newCodesSelect[index] = $(this).selectize({         
               valueField: 'id',
               labelField: 'label',
               create: false,
               hideSelected: false,
               options: listOptions[listType],          
               searchField: 'label',
               placeholder: "Choose " + listType + " codes (type to search)",
               maxItems: 1,
               onChange: function(value) {
                    // not needed?
               }
               //TODO 'add new'
            });
            //This stores the selectize object to a variable
            newCodesSelectize[index] = newCodesSelect[index][0].selectize;
```

This is what the rendered HTML looks like for one of the selectize options.

```html
<div class="col-4"> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control code_select selectized requiredField" id="5-tree-Betpap-stdCodeSelect" name="5-tree-Betpap-stdCode" aria-label="Tree Metric Field 5  Standard Code select" tabindex="-1" value="" style="display: none;">
    <div class="selectize-control form-control code_select single">
        <div class="selectize-input items not-full has-options">
           <input type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="" id="5-tree-Betpap-stdCodeSelect-selectized" placeholder="Choose species codes (type to search)" style="width: 271.812px;" class="requiredField">
        </div>
        <div class="selectize-dropdown single form-control code_select" style="display: none;">
            <div class="selectize-dropdown-content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot showing the text field, with the red border, and the selectize field without:
[image]

Any ideas are appreciated, thank you!

Comment: it looks to me like it is working propperly. can you explain a bit more?

https://jsfiddle.net/GuyNachshon/uf37knxq/2/

Comment: so strange!  I added a screenshot so you can see what I'm looking at.  If I look in the developer console, the added class isn't there since it is added dynamically, so I'm not sure how to tell if something is over-riding it?  But I put !important in the CSS so I'm not sure what could possibly be happening on my page!

Comment: I was able to track down that selectize has !important on the border css declarations as well.  My css file is linked to after the selectize css, so I'm not sure why it wasn't overriding it.  I manually updated the selectize css and removed !important from the border declarations to get it to work.